# Setting PEM attributes for user identities in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have a single-org setup running with one Fabric CA. CA Server is running with MySQL. I'm using NodeSDK to connect and issue transactions to chaincode.

I'm able to set Country, State, Locality, Organisation and Organisation Unit attributes for the peers and orderers. However, when I register and enroll "users" with the Fabric, not all attributes are being set. Only the Common Name and Organisation Unit attributes are set as seen from the certificate file.

Following is my snippet for registering and enrolling users:

```
await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: false } });

ca = await gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();

const secret = await ca.register({
                affiliation: user.$affiliation,
                enrollmentID: user.$name,
                role: user.$role,
               }, adminIdentity);

const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
                    enrollmentID: user.$name,
                    enrollmentSecret: secret,
                 });
const userIdentity = await X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(process.env.ACTIVE_MSP, enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
```

Here, "user" is a model for a participant that I'm using in my application. The Common Name (CN) is set to "enrollmentID" and Organisation Unit is set to "role" + "affiliation" and the resultant certificate for the user has the following information:

```
Owner: CN=jondoe, OU=client + OU=admin.forwarder.com
Issuer: CN=ca.allparticipants.logistics.com, 
O=allparticipants.logistics.com, L=Bengaluru, ST=Karnataka, C=IN
Serial number: ea385863390c07c320fd6717de7878fd9f81dc3e
Valid from: Mon Apr 15 14:11:00 IST 2019 until: Tue Apr 14 14:16:00 IST 2020
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  …<value>
     SHA1: …<value>
     SHA256: …<value>
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withECDSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 256-bit EC key
Version: 3

Extensions: 
…
```

As we can see, complete C, ST, L, O, OU and CN attributes of the Issuer is available. This belongs to MSP of the respective Org. However, only CN and OU of the user is available.

So is there a way with which we can set other attributes of the user (C, ST, L and O) while registering or enrolling user. Or do we have to infer these attributes from the issuer information?

*Update: 1*:
I checked the fabric-ca-client cli options which the node-sdk calls internally. Checked the register api. It does not give an option to set C, ST, L, and O either.

*Updates*:
Does fabric-ca support setting these attributes to the Subject Name?

*Update: 2*:
Going through the documentation of fabric-ca-client and as suggested by @nyet, I observed that we can set these values in csr.names attribute and supply it to 'csr' argument of the enroll command. The updated code snippet below:

```
await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: false } });

ca = await gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
```

adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();

```
const secret = await ca.register({
            affiliation: user.$affiliation,
            enrollmentID: user.$name,
            role: user.$role,
           }, adminIdentity);

const csrObj: any = {};
csrObj.names = 'O=Forwarder,C=IN,ST=Karnataka,L=Bengaluru';

const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
            csr: csrObj.toString(),
            enrollmentID: user.$name,
            enrollmentSecret: secret,
            });

const userIdentity = await X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(process.env.ACTIVE_MSP, enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
```

However, I get an error with this that says:

> Failed to enroll smithdoe20, error:%o message=Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"{\"code\":9002,\"
>   message\":\"CSR Decode failed\"}"}]], stack=Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"{\"code\":9002,\"message\":\"CSR Decode failed\"}"}]]

Similar JIRA issue: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-14051?jql=project%20%3D%20FAB%20AND%20statusCategory%20!%3D%20Done%20AND%20type%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20component%20%3D%20fabric-sdk-node%20AND%20project%20%3D%20FAB%20ORDER%20BY%20createdDate%20ASC

*Update: 3*:
The Node-SDK documentation states that the CSR field should be a PEM-encoded PKCS#10 certificate signing request.

1. I tried utilizing node-forge npm module to generate keys and sign proposal using it. However, that gives RSA keys.
2. Tried using node-pem. Didn't work out either.

Finally, tried generating the ECDSA keys and created a CSR offline using the following commands:
 1. Keys generation: openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out my-key.pem
 2. CSR: openssl req -new -sha256 -key my-key.pem -out my.csr

Read this CSR from the file system and passed it to Enrolment Request as follows:

```
 const csrNewVal = readFileSync('/Users/mrudavshukla/projects/pem-trials/ecdsa/my.csr', 'utf8');
 const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
                    csr: csrNewVal,
                    enrollmentID: user.$name,
                    enrollmentSecret: secret,
                });
```

Was able to enroll the user successfully.

Now, when we're passing the CSR, fabric-ca does not return us the enrolment key back. Thus, I retrieved the private key from #1 command from the file system and tried saving this user's identity details in X509 wallet as follows:

```
const privateNewVal = readFileSync('/Users/mrudavshukla/projects/pem-trials/ecdsa/my-key.pem', 'utf8');
const userIdentity = await X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(process.env.ACTIVE_MSP, enrollment.certificate, privateNewVal);
```

However, this throws the following error:

> error: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: importKey - {"message":"Does not understand PEM contents other than ECDSA private keys and certificates","stack":"Error: Does not understand PEM contents other than ECDSA private keys and certificates....

Next, I tried checking the certificate that was saved for this user with the one that fabric-ca generates when we do not supply CSR. Both are quite identical in structure and the signature algorithms used for the public key.

Am I missing out on any critical portion?

Comment: This will not work .... as the API docs specify, the optional `csr` field of the `EnrollmentRequest` actually needs to be a PEM-encoded PKCS10 certificate request.

Comment: @GariSingh Tried it. Is it that keys should be generated with ECDSA and not RSA? I tried one of the npm module that offered RSA keys and created a csr with it and was able to submit EnrolmentRequest. However, while creating an identity for wallet using X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(...) it throws an exception that says: "message":"Does not understand PEM contents other than ECDSA private keys and certificates".

Comment: You definitely need to use ECDSA

Comment: @GariSingh: Tried doing the same with ECDSA keys and signed the CSR with that certificate. Still, it throws the same exception. Replication steps: Update #3 in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no point looking out for additional modules to generate ECDSA keys and signing CSR with those keys. The fabric itself provides modules to do that. Solution steps below:

1. 'fabric-client' module provides CryptoSuite implementation. Using this crypto suite we can generate keys. These keys will be ECDSA 256 bit keys.
2. We can use 'jsrsasign' module to create a CSR. We can pass the keys generated in #1 to the method along with the subject info while creating the CSR. Its implementation will sign it. Fabric internally uses this method when we do not pass CSR.
3. Next, pass this CSR to EnrollmentRequest.
4. While creating an identity for storing into the wallet using X509WalletMixin, use certificate from the enrollment request and keys generated from #1.

Code below:

```
await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: false } });

ca = await gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();

const secret = await ca.register({
                affiliation: user.$virtualOrganizationBranch,
                enrollmentID: user.$name,
                role: user.$role,
            }, adminIdentity);

const privateKey = await hfc.newCryptoSuite().generateKey({ephemeral: true});

const subjectDN: string = 'CN=' + user.$name + ',C=IN,ST=Karnataka,L=Bengaluru,O=Forwarder';

const asn1 = jsrsa.asn1;
const csr = asn1.csr.CSRUtil.newCSRPEM({
                sbjprvkey: privateKey.toBytes(),
                sbjpubkey: privateKey.getPublicKey().toBytes(),
                sigalg: 'SHA256withECDSA',
                subject: {str: asn1.x509.X500Name.ldapToOneline(subjectDN)},
            });

const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
                csr,
                enrollmentID: user.$name,
                enrollmentSecret: secret,
            });

const userIdentity = await X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(process.env.ACTIVE_MSP, enrollment.certificate, privateKey.toBytes());
await wallet.import(user.$name, userIdentity);
```

Comment: How can we specify other attributes, the one which we can while running fabric-ca-client. I am struggling to find solid documentation on jsrsa where it's specified.

Comment: Which attributes in particular? If you could provide me with a snippet of the command that you're running using fabric-ca-client, it will help me understand your problem better.

Comment: I am trying to run ```fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://peer.operator.skynet.com:peer.operator.skynet.com.pw@0.0.0.0:6050 --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts peer.operator.skynet.com```. Also apart from hosts, I would like to know list of other SAN attributes one can specify. I was specifically trying to add email of user to bind it to certificate and serve as authentication source of truth

Comment: 1. For assigning SANs you could actually pass an argument of extensions(ext) to `newCSRPEM` along with the above-mentioned arguments. `ext` accepts array of key-value pairs.  2. That would basically depend on your use-case. You could either specify common name as an email of the user or alternatively you could make use of attributes. Again, much depends on specific use-case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mrudav for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If using `fabric-ca-client`, 
`fabric-ca-client enroll --csr.names "O=Org,C=US,ST=State,L=Locality" ...` should work. I know this isn't node, but hopefully it gets you in the right direction.