# fabric-ca-client --csr.cn flag on nodeJS

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

As we know --csr.cn its the common name field of the certificate signing request. And using fabric-ca-client we can point --csr.cn ca.myOrg, but nodeJS fabric-ca-client expect certificate.

How i can do somefing like this:

fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://adminTester:passwordTester@ca:7054 --csr.cn ca.myOrg

on nodeJS?

```
const enrollment = await fabric_ca_client.enroll({
  enrollmentID: "adminTester",
  enrollmentSecret: "passwordTester",
  csr: ?
});
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687562/setting-pem-attributes-for-user-identities-in-hyperledger-fabric